# Order by not working for more than 10 items

Tags: xml, vb.net, sorting

I am trying to sort a xml using linq queries using the following code

```
Dim SortedFields = From field In feedXML.Descendants("fields")
Dim sFieldList = From field In SortedFields.Descendants("field") Order By field.@position
```

The xml is shown below, but the issue is it is ordering it in the following order
1,10,11,12,13,14...19,2,3,4,5,6,7
instead of 1,2,3,4,5....10,11,12,.....19.

Can anybody help me sorting it in the correct order?

```
<fields>
    <field position="'6'" tablename="Students" headername="6" fieldreference="ClientField1" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'7'" tablename="Students" headername="7" fieldreference="ClientField2" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'8'" tablename="Students" headername="8" fieldreference="ClientField3" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'9'" tablename="Students" headername="9" fieldreference="ClientField4" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'10'" tablename="Students" headername="10" fieldreference="ClientField5" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'1'" tablename="Students" headername="1" fieldreference="ClientField6" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'2'" tablename="Students" headername="2" fieldreference="ClientField7" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'3'" tablename="Students" headername="3" fieldreference="ClientField8" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'4'" tablename="Students" headername="4" fieldreference="ClientField9" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'5'" tablename="Students" headername="5" fieldreference="ClientField10" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'11'" tablename="Students" headername="11" fieldreference="ClientField11" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'12'" tablename="Students" headername="12" fieldreference="ClientField12" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'13'" tablename="Students" headername="13" fieldreference="ClientField13" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'14'" tablename="Students" headername="14" fieldreference="ClientField14" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'15'" tablename="Students" headername="15" fieldreference="ClientField15" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'16'" tablename="Students" headername="16" fieldreference="ClientField16" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'17'" tablename="Students" headername="17" fieldreference="ClientField17" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'18'" tablename="Students" headername="18" fieldreference="ClientField18" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
    <field position="'19'" tablename="Students" headername="19" fieldreference="ClientField19" orderbydirection="ASC" displaycolumn="T" />
</fields>
```

Comment: That's alphabetic order, not numeric order.

Comment: I'd also suggest changing the title of the question to something less misleading / sensational :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Paul Tomblin points out this is alphabeticical ordering.  If position is going to always be a number then you can cast it into an integer using (int?)

```
Dim SortedFields = From field In feedXML.Descendants("fields")
                            Dim sFieldList = From field In SortedFields.Descendants("field") Order By (int?)field.@position
```

Comment: Can you really do a conversion just like that in VB?

Comment: Order By Integer.Parse(field.@position) is the right expression..Thanks again!

Comment: DirectCast() or CInt() would be a more direct translation: they are operators, but Integer.Parse() is a function call.

Answer (score 3):

It's sorting in alphabetical order. You need to convert the `position` attribute to an integer in your Order By clause:

```
Dim SortedFields = From field In feedXML.Descendants("fields")
Dim sFieldList = From field In SortedFields.Descendants("field") _
    Order By CType(field.@position, Integer)
```

(Apologies if there's a better conversion available... that's the code suggested by the [XAttribute conversion operator page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358993.aspx))